# How you generate create query from existing table using java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have few tables I want to generate create query(ddl) from existing tables , and convert to postgres compatible one from oracle .

Answer (score 1):

DDL can be fetched by executing `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`, such as in this example:

```
SQL> set long 10000
SQL> set pagesize 0
SQL>
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT') from dual;

  CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."EMP"
   (    "EMPNO" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        "ENAME" VARCHAR2(10),
        "JOB" VARCHAR2(9),
        "MGR" NUMBER(4,0),
        "HIREDATE" DATE,
        "SAL" NUMBER(7,2),
        "COMM" NUMBER(7,2),
        "DEPTNO" NUMBER(2,0),
         CONSTRAINT "FK_EMP_DEPT" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPTNO")
          REFERENCES "SCOTT"."DEPT" ("DEPTNO") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USER_DATA"


SQL>
```

I don't know how to convert it to Postgres, though (not to mention *using Java*).